# no suitable driver found in jsp but the driver exist

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, tomcat, mssql-jdbc

I am using JSP for the first time and trying to do a web application.The problem I'm facing is that the Database connection works great if run from the App.java class, but if I run it from the JSP file it will throw a SQLException saying it didn't find a suitable driver. I put the driver in the server's classpath, in the WEB-INF/lib, in the project's build path as external JAR.

environment:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017,
sqljdbc_10.2/mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre11.jar
server:Tomcat v10.0.13
eclipse java ee ide

Error message:

```
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.13
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 9 2021 22:12:58 UTC
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 10.0.13.0
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\kirla\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.0.v20211012-1059\jre
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17+35
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\kirla\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\kirla\Downloads\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\kirla\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\kirla\Downloads\apache-tomcat-10.0.13
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\kirla\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1254
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:57 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\kirla\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.0.v20211012-1059\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/kirla/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/kirla/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\kirla\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\kirla\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\kirla\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\;C:\Users\kirla\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\kirla\eclipse;;.]
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:58 ÖÖ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:58 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1261] milliseconds
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:58 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:58 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.13]
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:59 ÖÖ org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:59 ÖÖ org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:59 ÖÖ org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 31, 2022 10:43:59 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1139] milliseconds
oopss
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-EFD0KAH:1433;DatabaseName=Blog;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at Controller.DBConnection.connDb(DBConnection.java:23)
    at Controller.BlogController.<init>(BlogController.java:14)
    at org.apache.jsp.View.cevap_jsp._jspService(cevap_jsp.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Mar 31, 2022 10:44:00 ÖÖ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/WebApplication] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [View/cevap.jsp] at line [50]

47:                         <div class="col-10">
48:                             <%
49:                             
50:                             List<BlogModel> list=ozelBlog.getBlogList();
51:                             
52:                             for(BlogModel blog:list){
53:                                 


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.conn" is null
    at Controller.BlogController.getBlogList(BlogController.java:23)
    at org.apache.jsp.View.cevap_jsp._jspService(cevap_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my Java codes.

DBConnection.java

public class DBConnection {

```
public Connection con = null;
public String host = "localhost";
public String serverName = "DESKTOP-EFD0KAH";
public int port = 1433;
public String dbName = "Blog";
public String properties = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
//public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-EFD0KAH:1433;DatabaseName= Hospital ;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverName+":"+port+";DatabaseName="+dbName+";"+properties;
public String user="sa";
public String password="123";


public DBConnection() {}

public Connection connDb() {
    try {
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        System.out.println("connected.");
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("oopss");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

BlogController.java

public class BlogController extends DBConnection {

```
DBConnection con = new DBConnection();
Connection conn = con.connDb();
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public ArrayList<BlogModel> getBlogList() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<BlogModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BlogModel post;
    try {
        String sorgu = "SELECT * FROM post";
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sorgu);
        while (rs.next()) {
            post = new BlogModel(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("title"), rs.getString("body"),
                    rs.getString("createdAt"), rs.getInt("published"));
            list.add(post);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

and the index.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.apache.coyote.ContinueResponseTiming"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="Controller.BlogController,Model.BlogModel,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%
    BlogController ozelBlog = new BlogController();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Awesome Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="bg-dark px-4 py-5 text-center text-white">
            <div class="container my-4">
                <div class="latest">
                    <p>Latest posts...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-group text-dark">
                    <div class=" row"
                        style="width: 100%; background-image: url(../img/thumb-1920-190787.jpg)">


                        <div class="col-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <%
                            
                            List<BlogModel> list=ozelBlog.getBlogList();
                            
                            for(BlogModel blog:list){
                                
                                
                            %>
                            <div class="card m-5">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/1.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">
                                        <%
                                        blog.getTitle();
                                        %>
                                    </h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        <%
                                        blog.getBody();
                                        %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <small class="text-muted">
                                        <%
                                        blog.getCreatedAt();
                                        %>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <%
                            }
                            %>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read through [Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java) yet? Seems like `DatabaseName=Hospital;` should be `database=Hospital;` instead.

Comment: This also seems important if you're wanting to use encrypted SQL connections, `INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path`

Comment: I dont really think the problem is in url because when i test code on main, its connects succesfuly and I can get datas from database. I cant get your second comment, I am using those properties because if I dont use it gives me another error.